# Binding one ListItem to multiple dropdown in .NET Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding

Maybe this is a very simple question for you .NET guys but since I come from a MFC C++ dev teams, this behavior all got our dev team wondering what was going on. (In MFC, when we create a dropdown datasource, the source is shared but the value of each dropdown is not affected)

It's a very simple situation. I have 3 dropdownlist in my form that ask for streets. The street you are on and the others 2 closest streets. Each of these dropdownlist have the same datasource. So what we did is that (by the way ComboList is just a class that inherit ListItem with some more functions)

```
//Combo Street
ComboList cboNomRue = new ComboList();
Tools.GetCombo(cboNomRue, Tools.ComboTypeRt.RT_NOM_RUE, true, true);
ddlNomRue.DisplayMember = "Numero";
ddlNomRue.ValueMember = "ID";
ddlNomRue.DataSource = cboNomRue;

//Combo Street From
ddlDe.DisplayMember = "Numero";
ddlDe.ValueMember = "ID";
ddlDe.DataSource = cboNomRue;

//Combo Street To
ddlA.DisplayMember = "Numero";
ddlA.ValueMember = "ID";
ddlA.DataSource = cboNomRue;
```

Using this code, when the user change the value in ddlNomRue, the 3 dropdownlist change to that value! So to fix that, I did that.

```
//Combo Street
ComboList cboNomRue = new ComboList();
Tools.GetCombo(cboNomRue, Tools.ComboTypeRt.RT_NOM_RUE, true, true);
ddlNomRue.DisplayMember = "Numero";
ddlNomRue.ValueMember = "ID";
ddlNomRue.DataSource = cboNomRue;

ComboList cboNomRue2 = new ComboList(cboNomRue);
ComboList cboNomRue3 = new ComboList(cboNomRue);

//Combo Street From
ddlDe.DisplayMember = "Numero";
ddlDe.ValueMember = "ID";
ddlDe.DataSource = cboNomRue2;

//Combo Street To
ddlA.DisplayMember = "Numero";
ddlA.ValueMember = "ID";
ddlA.DataSource = cboNomRue3;
```

I don't like this since it's duplicating variables when only one is really needed. Is this the good way of dealing with this situation or is there anything else I could do?

Thanks

Comment: Is this WPF?  I did this with ListView with no problem.

Comment: This isn't WPF. And I didn't say that it was not working. It's working  but I'm asking if there is a better way to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear about the ComboList Class used by you, but if you use the List to store the item which is to be displayed in comboBox is the better option.

The way adopted by you is not good because of creating object again and again. To overcome this, use List and just call it function AsReadOnly();

Example:

```
  List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();
            Mylist.Add("salman");
            Mylist.Add("khan");
            Mylist.Add("yousafzai");
            Mylist.Add("ranizai");
            Mylist.Add("kachokhail");




            this.tUsersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbAIASDataSet.tUsers);
            comboBox1.DataSource = Mylist.AsReadOnly();
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";


           comboBox2.DataSource = Mylist.AsReadOnly();
           comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ID";
           comboBox2.ValueMember = "ID";
```

But if you must have to use the Object of ComboList then implement the interface icloneable in ComboList or use any other way to create a shallow copy.

Comment: Thanks! The "AsReadOnly" was exactly the kind of thing I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

The form automatically create a default `BindingContext` for all objects on the form that support data binding. The `BindingContext` allows the form to know the count and current position of the collection entries within that object. When you select an item on the first list, you change its position and since the other two controls are bound with the same `BindingContext`, they all change as well. To fix this behavior, simply create a different `BindingContext` for each control as follow:

```
ddlNomRue.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
ddlDe.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
ddlA.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

Now you can bind the same `ComboList` to all three controls and you will still get the behavior that you want.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Yes the 3 dropdown are not changing when one of them changes but they do not bind anymore (they all start at N/D instead of their value). Thanks anyway :)